# Image getting zoomed and cut off when converting from binary data

Tags: c#-4.0, graphics

I have some background images stored as binary data. I need to draw something on it based on data and then show it as a single image in the browser. The issue is that some of the images are getting zoomed in and some get zoomed out when I try to do this with the following code. Can anyone please tell where I am going wrong?

```
int imageWidth = 0, imageHeight=0;
Image bmpImg;
if (datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    bmpImg = Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream((byte[])datatable.Rows[0]["data"]));
    imageWidth = bmpImg.Width;
    imageHeight= bmpImg.Height;
}
else{
bmpImg = null;
}

bitmap = new Bitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight);
//bitmap = new Bitmap(1000, 800);
renderer = SvgRenderer.FromImage(bitmap);
graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
if(bmpImg != null)
{
    graphics.DrawImage(bmpImg, 0, 0);
}
//perform other drawings using graphics
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
bitmap.Dispose();
renderer.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I got the answer from another question : [Graphics.DrawImage unexpectedly resizing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103146/graphics-drawimage-unexpectedly-resizing-image)

Basically you have to change this:

graphics.DrawImage(bmpImg, 0, 0);

to

graphics.DrawImage(bmpImg,new Rectangle(0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight));