# printing a bitmap with GDI+ is distorted

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, printing, mfc

So I'm trying to print a one page document. I'm basically drawing text and blting bitmaps onto a page-size bitmap, then blting THAT bitmap on the printer's DC

`nPixWidth = 5100` and `nPixHeight = 6600`, so how is a bitmap 445 x 1092 taking up the ENTIRE top of the page? Like, what the heck? What am I missing here?

I don't have to use GDI+. I could use `DrawText` and `BitBlt` or `StretchBlt`, but I thought GDI+ would be better.

```
    int nPixWidth = GetDeviceCaps(m_hPrinterDC, PHYSICALWIDTH), nPixHeight = GetDeviceCaps(m_hPrinterDC, PHYSICALHEIGHT);
    int nPixMarginWidth = GetDeviceCaps(m_hPrinterDC, PHYSICALOFFSETX), nPixMarginHeight = GetDeviceCaps(m_hPrinterDC, PHYSICALOFFSETY);
//  int nDPI = nPixHeight / GetDeviceCaps(m_hPrinterDC, )
    Bitmap myBitmap(nPixWidth - nPixMarginWidth, nPixHeight - nPixMarginHeight, PixelFormat32bppARGB);
    HBITMAP hLogoBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP_THELOGO_HORZ), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0);  // 445 x 1092
    GetPaperDimensions(m_cReportOptions.m_devMode.dmPaperSize, m_fPageWidth, m_fPageHeight);
    Graphics printer(m_hPrinterDC); 
    Graphics page(&myBitmap);
    Bitmap *pBmpLogo = Bitmap::FromHBITMAP(hLogoBmp, NULL);
    int nLogoWidth = pBmpLogo->GetWidth(), nLogoHeight = pBmpLogo->GetHeight();
    SolidBrush whiteBrush(Color(255, 255, 255));
    page.FillRectangle(&whiteBrush, 0, 0, nPixWidth - nPixMarginWidth, nPixHeight - nPixMarginHeight);
    page.DrawImage(pBmpLogo, 0, 0, nLogoWidth, nLogoHeight);
    printer.DrawImage(&myBitmap, 0, 0); // , (INT)nPixWidth, (INT)nPixHeight);
    DeleteObject(hLogoBmp);
    delete pBmpLogo;
```

Comment: Not an expert for GDI, but I suspect that the DPI (resolution, part of bitmap metadata) are considered. I found another Q/A which seems to prove my suspicion. It's tagged [tag:C#] and [tag:.Net] but might/should be applicable to your issue: [SO: Graphics.DrawImage unexpectedly resizing image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18103957/7478597)

Comment: [Mapping Modes and Translations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/mapping-modes-and-translations).